# Регулярное выражение не обрабатывает символ перевода строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение на Python. Имеем HTML страницу. Вот часть ее содержимого:

```
<p>На сегодняшний день PHP является наиболее распространенным языком веб-программирования. Подавляющие большинство сайтов и веб-сервисов в интернете 
написано с помощью PHP. По некоторым оценкам PHP применяется более чем на 80% сайтов, среди которых такие сервисы, как facebook.com, vk.com, baidu.com и 
другие. И такая популярность неудивительна. Простота языка позволяет быстро и легко создавать сайты и порталы различной сложности.</p>
<p>PHP был создан в 1994 году датским программистом Расмусом Лердорфом и изначально представлял собой набор скриптов на другом языке Perl. Позже этот 
набор скриптов был переписан в интерпретатор на языке Си. И с самого возникновения PHP (сокращение от PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor - PHP: Препроцессор гипертекста) 
представлял удобный набор инструментов для упрощенного создания веб-сайтов и веб-приложений.</p>
<p>Какие преимущества предоставляет PHP?</p>
```

Необходимо найти весь текст который заключен между тегами `<p> </p>`.

Составил выражение: `".*<p>(.*)"`

На выходе получаю:

> "На сегодняшний день PHP является наиболее распространенным языком
>   веб-программирования. Подавляющие большинство сайтов и веб-сервисов в
>   интернете "

После слова интернете "интернете" я так понимаю есть "\n" поэтому моё РВ не срабатывает. Как составить правильно? Необходимо все, что заключено между каждыми `"<p)"  </p)` использую `re.findall`

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте к методу регулярки флаг [re.DOTALL](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

В доке есть описание этого флага:

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a
> newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

т.е. без флага `re.DOTALL` символ `.` будет матчить любой символ, кроме символа новой строки

Пример:

```py
import re

text = """<p>На сегодняшний день PHP является наиболее распространенным языком веб-программирования. Подавляющие большинство сайтов и веб-сервисов в интернете
написано с помощью PHP. По некоторым оценкам PHP применяется более чем на 80% сайтов, среди которых такие сервисы, как facebook.com, vk.com, baidu.com и
другие. И такая популярность неудивительна. Простота языка позволяет быстро и легко создавать сайты и порталы различной сложности.</p>
<p>PHP был создан в 1994 году датским программистом Расмусом Лердорфом и изначально представлял собой набор скриптов на другом языке Perl. Позже этот
набор скриптов был переписан в интерпретатор на языке Си. И с самого возникновения PHP (сокращение от PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor - PHP: Препроцессор гипертекста)
представлял удобный набор инструментов для упрощенного создания веб-сайтов и веб-приложений.</p>
<p>Какие преимущества предоставляет PHP?</p>
"""

match = re.search(r'.*<p>(.*)', text)
print(match.group())
print()

match = re.search(r'.*<p>(.*)', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(match.group())
```

Консоль:

```
<p>На сегодняшний день PHP является наиболее распространенным языком веб-программирования. Подавляющие большинство сайтов и веб-сервисов в интернете

<p>На сегодняшний день PHP является наиболее распространенным языком веб-программирования. Подавляющие большинство сайтов и веб-сервисов в интернете
написано с помощью PHP. По некоторым оценкам PHP применяется более чем на 80% сайтов, среди которых такие сервисы, как facebook.com, vk.com, baidu.com и
другие. И такая популярность неудивительна. Простота языка позволяет быстро и легко создавать сайты и порталы различной сложности.</p>
<p>PHP был создан в 1994 году датским программистом Расмусом Лердорфом и изначально представлял собой набор скриптов на другом языке Perl. Позже этот
набор скриптов был переписан в интерпретатор на языке Си. И с самого возникновения PHP (сокращение от PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor - PHP: Препроцессор гипертекста)
представлял удобный набор инструментов для упрощенного создания веб-сайтов и веб-приложений.</p>
<p>Какие преимущества предоставляет PHP?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Необходимо найти весь текст который заключен между тегами <p> </p>. Составил выражение: .*<p>(.*) На выходе получаю:
```

Наверное правильнее для этого условия написать регулярное выражение `<p>(.*?)<\/p>` с флагами gs