# python regular expression содержимое квадратных скобок

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка

```
text = '''
out: out out out kkk: aaa_aaa_aaa
ttt ttt: [ttt: ttt = "" ttt ttt ttt ttt ttt; ttt ttt: ttt ttt ttt-45645645 ttt ttt - 23.10.2020. ttt ttt ttt ttt ttt!
(ttt-ttt-00151) (ttt ttt: 99)"" ttt: ]
out kkk: out out out
out kkk: out out out out out out out.out out.out out
'''
```

Нужно получить с помощью регулярного выражения

```
ttt ttt: [ttt: ttt = "" ttt ttt ttt ttt ttt; ttt ttt: ttt ttt ttt-45645645 ttt ttt - 23.10.2020. ttt ttt ttt ttt ttt!
    (ttt-ttt-00151) (ttt ttt: 99)"" ttt: ]
```

Пытался использовать `re.findall(r'ttt ttt:\s*\[.*\]', text)`, но безуспешно. Как можно решить такую задачу?

Comment: `re.findall(r"([\n\r][^\n\r\[]*\[[^\]]*\])", text, flags=re.S | re.M)` ?

Comment: Не знал , как флаги использовать, спасибо , что показали. В итоге сразу дошло, что можно было мой вариант с флагом использовать. re.findall(r'out out:\s*\[.*\]', text, flags=re.DOTALL)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Регулярное выражение не обрабатывает символ перевода строки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/686940/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.findall(r'ttt ttt:\s*\[.*\]', text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```